# Typescript React HOC Woes

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm having a ton of trouble getting typescript to cooperate with my HOC. After many iterations, here's the best I've got:

```js
export interface IRequiresLoginProps {
  loggedIn: boolean;
}

type GetProps<C> = C extends ComponentType<infer P> ? P : never;

function requiresLogin<C extends ComponentType<GetProps<C>>>(Component: C) {
  const MakeTSHappy: ComponentType<GetProps<C>> = Component;
  const displayName = Component.displayName || Component.name || "Component";

  class RequiresLogin extends PureComponent<GetProps<C> & IRequiresLoginProps> {
    public static readonly displayName = `RequiresLogin(${displayName})`;

    public render() {
      const {loggedIn, ...props} = this.props as IRequiresLoginProps;
      return loggedIn ? <MakeTSHappy {...props} /> : <Login loggedIn={loggedIn} />;
    }
  }
  return hoistNonReactStatics(RequiresLogin, Component);
}
```

For some reason, the only way to make typescript happy is by using the `MakeTSHappy` variable. If I try to skip it and use Component directly like `<Component {...props} />`, TS errors with: "JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures."

Since the type of `Component` extends `ComponentType<>`, I would expect it to work just like a `ComponentType<>`; why does it give me an error? The fact that I can assign it to a variable of type `ComponentType<>` without explicitly casting it seems to back up my understanding.

Comment: *JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures* - there should also be an explanation why the type doesn't match in this message.

Comment: sadly, no =( That's all I get.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just overcomplicating it a bit, as HOCs existed before conditional types appeared.. this works fine:

```
function requiresLogin<P extends {}, C extends ComponentType<P> = ComponentType<P>>(
  Component: ComponentType<P>
) {
  const displayName = Component.displayName || Component.name || "Component";

  class RequiresLogin extends PureComponent<P & IRequiresLoginProps> {
    public static readonly displayName = `RequiresLogin(${displayName})`;

    public render() {
      const { loggedIn, ...props } = this.props as IRequiresLoginProps;
      return loggedIn ? <Component {...props} /> : <Login loggedIn={loggedIn} />;
    }
  }
  return hoistNonReactStatics(RequiresLogin, Component);
}
```

Comment: This is similar to what I started with, but you aren't using type parameter `C` anywhere. If you replace `Component: ComponentType<P>` with `Component: C` you'll run into the same error I was getting: JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.

Comment: If you remove type parameter `C` (since you aren't using it anyway), it works fine, but the return value of the HOC isn't quite right: because `Component` is declared as `ComponentType<P>`, the return type of `hoistNonReactStatics` doesn't contain any of the statics on Component.

Comment: but why would you need to replace ComponenType<P> with C if it works fine already? :-) At least as far as types are concerned.

Comment: unfortunately I don't know about hoistNOnReactStatics thing, so it might not work then

Comment: static properties and methods don't belong to class interface anyway, so maybe it should be done somehow differently, however here I am not sure, sorry